# Vuetify validation not working on ios input but on blur it validates

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have this code for validation year field, it works fine on android input but when I test on ios it validates on blur.

```
                <VTextField
                  type="text"
                  pattern="[0-9]*"
                  inputmode="numeric"
                  id="imuwlifestoryYear"
                  :rules="[dateValidator]"
                  maxlength="4"                    
                  hide-details="false"
                  required
                  v-model="eventYear"
                  @keypress="onlyNumber"
                >
                </VTextField>
```

Validation function

```
dateValidator (val) {
      let message = "Date is invalid";
      if(!val) return message;
      return Number(val) > 999 && /^\d+$/.test(val) && Number(val) <= new Date().getFullYear() || message;
    }
```

How can I make it validate as user types?
I even tried using `@update:modelValue` event but it doesn't work.